# How can I create a named pipe with c++ in Windows so that data can be read from it as if it were a regular file, given the pipe's name?

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes

## Problem

Due to some unusual requirements, I would like to be able to open a named pipe from c++ code in Windows from its name as if it were a regular "file path," rather than using `ReadFile`.

### Code

I have written server and client code to read and write from a named pipe in Windows.

#### Server Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // Client will block if not in a thread.
    const TCHAR *pipe_name = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe");

    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead;

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            1,
                            1024 * 16,
                            1024 * 16,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                            NULL);

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // This will block if there's no client.
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)
    {
        // Read from the pipe
        DWORD bytesRead = 0;
        BOOL success = ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &bytesRead, NULL);

        if (!success || bytesRead == 0)
        {
            std::cerr << "ReadFile failed, error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[bytesRead] = '\0'; // null terminate
            std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << std::endl;
        }
    }

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);
```

#### Client Code

Note that I have used `fstream` and the pipe name as a "file path" rather than more common `WriteFile`, but it works as I want:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const TCHAR *pipe_name = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe");

    std::cout << "Running client. This uses fstream..." << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {
        if (WaitNamedPipe(pipe_name, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER) != FALSE)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting for pipe server..." << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open(pipe_name, std::fstream::out); // Works!

    if (fs.is_open())
    {
        fs << "Hello, Pipe Server!";
        fs.close();
        std::cout << "Client is done." << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to open the pipe." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

#### Client Code, Alternative

The alternative client code, shown below, works too.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const TCHAR *pipe_name = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe");

    std::cout << "Running client. This uses WriteFile..." << std::endl;

    while (true)
    {
        if (WaitNamedPipe(pipe_name, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER) != FALSE)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting for pipe server..." << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwWritten;

    hPipe = CreateFile(pipe_name,
                       GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                       0,
                       NULL,
                       OPEN_EXISTING,
                       0,
                       NULL);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        WriteFile(hPipe,
                  "Hello, Pipe Server!",
                  strlen("Hello, Pipe Server!") + 1,
                  &dwWritten,
                  NULL);
        CloseHandle(hPipe);
        std::cout << "Client is done." << std::endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect to pipe server, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

All versions compile and run as expected under Visual Studio Code, using `cl.exe /Zi /EHsc /Fe: <file>.exe <file>.cpp`.

### Outputs

With the client version of the code using `fstream` and a "file path" I obtain the following outputs:

#### Server First

Started first, doesn't output until the client starts:

```
Received: Hello, Pipe Server!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

#### Client Next

Started next, outputs immediately:

```
Running client. This uses fstream...
Client is done.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

For what's worth, inverting the order of execution also produces good results.

#### Client First

Started first, outputs the waiting message immediately and success message once the server starts:

```
Running client. This uses fstream...
Waiting for pipe server...
Waiting for pipe server...
Waiting for pipe server...
Client is done.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

#### Server Next

Outputs immediately:

```
Received: Hello, Pipe Server!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

## Summary

The problem is that I would like to use the pipe name treated as a regular file path to read the data, rather than the traditional `ReadFile`. I was able to write data to the pipe using that approach, but the reading failed. Ironically (and think it might actually be correct to describe this a situational irony), I don't really care for how the data is written to the pipe - I would be happy with using `WriteFile` for that, but I would really like to use the pipe's name as if it were a regular file path to read the data.

## What I Tried

I have tried variants of the server code shown below, combined with both versions of the client code.

### Attempted Server Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    // Client will block if not in a thread.
    const TCHAR *pipe_name = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe");

    HANDLE hPipe;
    char buffer[1024];
    DWORD dwRead;

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            1,
                            1024 * 16,
                            1024 * 16,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                            NULL);

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // This will block if there's no client.
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)
    {
        std::ifstream fs;
        fs.open(pipe_name, std::fstream::in);

        if (fs.is_open())
        {
            std::string line;
            while (std::getline(fs, line))
            {
                std::cout << "Received: " << line << std::endl;
            }
            fs.close();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Server failed to open the pipe with ifstream." << std::endl;
        }

    }

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

#### Variants

Mostly desperation, not much thought put behind it. I have tried creating the named pipe with `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` instead of just `PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX`, with and without combining that with changing the pipe type from `PYPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE` to `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`, to no avail. Finally, I have also tried opening the `fstream` with `std::fstream::in | std::fstrem::out` and with `std::fstream::binary`. No dice. All of these attempts produced the output below.

### New Outputs

On the client side I have the same output as before. On the server side, with everything I tried, I get instead

```
Server failed to open the pipe with ifstream.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The fact that an almost exact counterpart to what I want works to write data gives me hope that this can be made to work to read data, but, of course, I am fully aware that this is not guaranteed.

### Other Potential Solutions (And Why They Do Not Work for Me)

There are claims in [Read Named Pipe with _lread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113216/read-named-pipe-with-lread) that it is possible to do what I am looking for using `_lopen`, but I don't have control over how the transaction with the pipe will be conducted, other than that it will be treated as a regular file for the purposes of reading data.

Despite claims to the contrary ([Fifo file Windows example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31625417/fifo-file-windows-example)), I could not find a real example of how to do a `mkfifo`-equivalent in Windows ([using istream to read from named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740914/using-istream-to-read-from-named-pipe)).

Comment: XY answer: When I need to do something like this, it's usually for compatibility with other platforms. I'll abstract the problem behind an interface so the client code always gets what it wants and the implementation can vary by platform either with conditional compilation or a smarter built script. For example, the Windows implementation does something completely different from the POSIX implementation, and both are hidden away in the back end somewhere.

Comment: The read failed how?

Comment: If you want to read/write a named pipe like a stream, create a stream buffer that reads and writes the named pipe in its underflow/overflow functions. Here's a sample echo server and client written this way: https://godbolt.org/z/bM8a5WPPY. To test, you run two instances, one with `server` as a command line argument, and it sends a little data back and forth. Start the server first--I didn't include the extra loop to allow starting the client first, but you can add that back in if you want.

Comment: `fs.open(pipe_name, std::fstream::in);` in the server makes no sense. You are becoming a client of yourself. The server needs to do its I/O via `hPipe`.

Comment: @user207421, the read failed because the check `fs.is_open()` returns false in the server.

Comment: That doesn't make sense either. The `fs.open()` in the server doesn't make sense in the first place, but if it failed, as it would have, it would have printed `"Server failed to open the pipe with ifstream."`. That doesn't tell us how the read in the client failed. NB I didn't ask *why* it failed, I asked *how.* Namely, an error code or message.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I don't have the flexibility to do what you suggest; @user4581301 correctly guessed that I have to enforce compatibility with other platforms, and that places some restrictions on me. I won't belabor the point, as the question has been closed, but following the gist of @user207421 comments I more or less inverted the roles of the server and the client, and that does allow me to read from the pipe as if it were a regular file, with `fs.open(pipe_name, std::fstream::in)`, which meets my requirements. Thank you all for your comments and help.

Comment: The question has been reopened, so for sake of completeness I'll post the solution, based on @user207421's suggestion, that worked for me. If that user wishes to write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The following server/client code below, which can be contrasted with the code I tried before, was the solution that worked for me, in the spirit of @user207421's suggestion.

### Server

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const TCHAR *pipe_name = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe");
    HANDLE hPipe;
    DWORD dwRead;

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipe_name,
                            PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE,
                            PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE | PIPE_WAIT,
                            1,
                            1024,
                            1024,
                            NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
                            NULL);

    if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // This will block if there's no client.
    if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) != FALSE)
    {
        DWORD dwRead;
        char buffer[20];
        if (!ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, &dwRead, NULL))
        {
            std::cout << "ReadFile failed, GLE=" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer[dwRead] = '\0';
            std::cout << "Received: " << buffer << std::endl;
        }

        DWORD dwWritten;
        WriteFile(hPipe,
                  "Hello, Pipe Client!",
                  strlen("Hello, Pipe Client!") + 1,
                  &dwWritten,
                  NULL);
        std::cout << "Server is done." << std::endl;
    }

    DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

### Client

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    const TCHAR *pipe_name = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\Pipe");

    while (true)
    {
        if (WaitNamedPipe(pipe_name, NMPWAIT_WAIT_FOREVER) != FALSE)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Waiting for pipe server..." << std::endl;
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open(pipe_name, std::fstream::in);
    if (fs.is_open())
    {
        fs << "Hello, Pipe Server!" << std::endl;
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(fs, line))
        {
            std::cout << "Received: " << line << std::endl;
        }
        fs.close();

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Server failed to open the pipe with ifstream." << std::endl;

        return 1;
    }
}
```

### Outputs

#### Starting Server First, Client Next

##### Server

```
Received: Hello, Pipe Client!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

##### Client

```
Received: Hello, Pipe Server!
Server is done.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

#### Starting Client First, Server Next

##### Client

```
Waiting for pipe server...
Waiting for pipe server...
Received: Hello, Pipe Client!
Press any key to continue . . .
```

##### Server

```
Received: Hello, Pipe Server!
Server is done.
Press any key to continue . . .
```